# nginx: how to ban a user dropping connection (no 403)

Tags: nginx

Is there a way to drop/ignore an http/ssl (port 80/443) request from a banned ip instead of returning a 403 error?

I'd like it to be handled by Nginx if possible, not iptables.

Answer (score 1):

If you cause your nginx configuration to return status code `444`, nginx will immediately drop the connection.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that status code. Would you have an usage example? Currently I'm just including a cfg file within the nginx.conf file. (That cfg file has "deny xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;", one per line)

Comment: Try `error_page 403 =444;`

Comment: You'll need to have a URI on that `error_page` directive, too.

Comment: Well there's no point if I still return a page setting an URI instead of dropping the connection, am I right?

Comment: Yes, but that's not how the `error_page` directive expects its arguments to be structured.